# Cloudant replication errors: TDChangeTracker (Code=589) and NSURLErrorDomain(Code=-1005)

Tags: ios, node.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have been using Cloudant through Bluemix and everything worked fine at the beginning. But now the replications don't complete successful anymore, constantly throwing errors or finishing with no data being received.

> replicatorDidError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "(null)"
>
> replicatorDidError: Error Domain=TDChangeTracker Code=589 "(null)"
>
> Bad DB response: {"error":"service_unavailable","reason":"Service unavailable"}

Sometimes it was temporarily fixed assigning new credentials, but now it doesn't do the trick anymore. It happens either from the iOS SDK or from a node.js app.

Any help will be very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of CDTDatastore are you using? Is the network available and usable when you get this error?

Comment: @rhyshort yes, the network is totally available and usable. We are using the latest version on the `master` branch: https://github.com/cloudant/CDTDatastore

Comment: Seriously don't use the head of master for production. Also raise a ticket on GitHub will a full set of logs, the commit SHA which you are using.

Comment: @rhyshort Thanks for the help! We are not using it for production, we were testing the background replication functionality which is only available in `master`. We assumed that `master` would be a stable branch and not used for development.

Comment: It tends to be stable, but sometimes things can slip through reviews and testing